# Does a flight instructor rating supercede a ground instructor rating?

Tags: faa-regulations, cfi, ground-instructor

In the FAA jurisdiction, if an instructor candidate were to become a ground instructor (advanced and instrument) and receive that certificate, then later become a flight instructor (and CFII), would there be any value in retaining the ground instructor certificate? The flight instructor certificates held at that point provide all the same privileges. Is the ground instructor certificate superceded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The flight instructor certificates held at that point provide all the same privileges.

This is not true.  A ground instructor certificate is valid to give ground training for all aircraft... airplane, helicopter, glider, balloon, etc.  A flight instructor must have those ratings on their certificate.

Record keeping requirements also differ between the two certificates.

[§61.189(b)(2)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c3d649e2753f4928a7ce1f471d08c724&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_1189&rgn=div8) requires the flight instructor to keep a record of all knowledge test endorsements to include the student name, date, kind of test and result.

The ground instructor has no such requirement.

---

The flight instructor must also have an advanced or instrument ground instructor certificate to qualify for a gold seal.

Comment: How do record keeping requirements differ?

Comment: Just to clarify another point; they are still treated as two separate certificates.  So if one were to sign ground work off under their AGI number and get dinged on some technicality by the FAA and had their instructor cert. suspended it would essentially protect the flight instructor cert.  . . . or so I have been told over and over again.